# TinyMCE 4 remove/add attributes for all images

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce, tinymce-4

i want to search for all images that have been add to TinyMCE 4 and:

1. Remove the height attribute from the images
2. Add style="max-width: 100%;" to all images

   - I am working with wordpress.

what is the best way to do this tasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**Pure javascript:**

```
var body = tinymce.get('your_editor_id').getBody();

[].forEach.call(
  body.querySelectorAll('img'), 
  function(el){
    el.removeAttribute('heigth');
    el.setAttribute("style", "max-width: 100%;");
  }
);
```

**Or using jQuery:**

```
var body = tinymce.get('your_editor_id').getBody();
$(body).find('img').removeAttr('height').css('max-width', '100%');
```